# Silverlight Controls Edit Value

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-2.0

```
TextBox1.DataBinding.Add("Text",dataset.Tables["Sample"],"Id");
TextBox2.DataBinding.Add("Text",dataset.Tables["Sample"],"Name");
```

How Can I make this in Silverlight?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to bind a single textbox to multiple values?

Comment: What research have you done already? There are plenty of data binding tutorials on the web.

Comment: You have a fairly long journey to go on. Begin here: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-4-videos/wcf-and-data-entity-modeling-in-silverlight/ to get a flavour of the sort of thing you are getting into.